# Facebook AdCampaign Missing

Tags: php, composer-php, facebook-ads-api

i already search all over, and AdCampaign file is missing (FacebookAds\Object\AdCampaign). In this github is missing too. ([Github FB link](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/tree/master/src/FacebookAds/Object))

But in your usage examples you use it as a Campaign getter info.

I already installed/tested composer, and its fine.

Checked where composer searchs for class and file isn't there.

[image]
Any help?

Comment: can you post the link to the usage examples?

Comment: if you refer to the Facebook doc (as example [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api#campaign)) some typo can exists in some parts

Comment: @Matteo, yeah, i'm using those docs. This one ([link]https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api/getting-started) .
as you can see:  

`code`
use FacebookAds\Object\AdCampaign;  
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\InsightsPresets;  

$campaign = new AdCampaign('<AD_CAMPAIGN_ID>');  
`code`  
Thats where AdCampaign gives me the error, but i'm able to open other libreries from this api.

Comment: hi, probably is a typo (as many others occurr in the doc of fb :)) the class have the method you refer https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/master/src/FacebookAds/Object/Campaign.php#L238

Comment: @Matteo, ty, but that is like a common method... ill keep searching, ty again!

Answer (score 2):

Facebook AdCampaign is renamed to Campaign as per as new changes so correct use is

```
use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
```